# I added the relaevant jar files in lib folder of jmeter and also added jar files in "Add directory or jar to classpath" but getting issues shown below

Tags: jmeter

```
2020-03-19 10:28:54,395 WARN o.a.j.e.BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.io.*; import java.util.*; import org.json.JSONObject; import org.jso . . . ''
2020-03-19 10:29:54,532 ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.io.*; import java.util.*; import org.json.JSONObject; import org.jso . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Class: JSONParser not found in namespace
```

I added the relaevant jar files in lib folder of jmeter and also added jar files in “Add directory or jar to classpath” but getting issues shown below

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to **restart JMeter** to pick up the .jar files you added to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting so consider migrating to [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor). Moreover Groovy has [built-in JSON support](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html) so most probably you won't need these extra libraries at all. See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) article for more details.